# How to implement a 'toggle class' function in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This function should search the document for any element with a 'data-info' attribute with a value of 'graphicDesign' then toggle the class 'hideMe' on those elements.

It returns the correct amount of elements in the console, but breaks on the classList toggle.

I've tried alternatives such as finding elements by class name then toggling, but this doesn't work either.

```
function toggleGraphicDesign() {
    let graphicDesignElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-info="graphicDesign"]');
    console.log(graphicDesignElements.length);

    graphicDesignElements.classList.toggle('hideMe');

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` return a NodeList not a single element.According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) **NodeList** representing a **list** of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

You need to loop through all the elements using `forEach()` and toggle class of each element.

```
function toggleGraphicDesign() {
    let graphicDesignElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-info="graphicDesign"]');
    console.log(graphicDesignElements.length);
    graphicDesignElements.forEach(x => x.classList.toggle('hideMe')) 
}
```